# Python Stepper motor shortest path

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to control a stepper motor and I'm trying to figure out how calculate the shortest direction to move from one position to another using the shortest direction.
[image]

I have a function which control in what direction and how many grades turn the motor. RotMotor(degrees, speed) positive degrees move clockwise direction and negative for anti-clockwise direction.

I'm trying to create a function with the origin degree and the target degree as parameters (for example 15 to 345) and return -30

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Subtract start degree from destination degree. If the absolute value is more than 180, use the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out by my self with this function. I think is correct.

def calcPath(origin,destination):

```
    if abs(destination - origin) <= 180:
            return (destination - origin)
    else:
            degrees =  360 - abs(destination - origin)
            if destination < 180:
                    return degrees
            else:
                    return -degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work just fine

> `diff = lambda x,y : (y-x if x>y else x-y) if abs(x-y)<180  else (abs(x-y-360) if x>y else abs(x-y)-360)`

example-

> `print(diff(15,345))`
>
> `>-30`

simplified version-

`def diff_fun(x,y):
  if abs(x-y) < 180:
    if x>y:
      return y-x
    else:
      return x-y
  else:
    if x>y:
      return abs(x-y-360)
    else:
      return abs(x-y)-360`

> `print(diff_fun(30,15))`
>
> -15

abs is used to find the absolute value

Comment: If try diff_fun(15,30) return -15 instead 15
this if: 
if x>y:
      return y-x
    else:
      return x-y
doesn't make sense I think